# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' in Thonny

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-import, thonny

I'm on Windows 10 trying to update someone's file to Python 3. In any case, I cannot import Pillow with `import PIL`, despite having the proper version installed and having uninstalled and reinstalled the library. What can I do? How can I discover the source of the problem?

I briefly tried installing Python 2; I hope this did not mess up my system or anything.

UPDATE: This issue occurs only in the Thonny IDE, not in the Python shell or IDLE.

Comment: This could be because you have multiple Python 3's installed. Trying installing it with the python command you're using to run your script `python3 -m pip install pillow` or `python3.8 -m pip install pillow` or whatever.

Comment: @Boris Thonny uses Python 3.7.9, whereas I use Python 3.9 otherwise. Could this be a problem?

Comment: yes. If you installed the module using Python 3.9's `pip` then it will not be available in Python 3.7 and vice-versa. Modules are not (usually) shared across Python installations. You need to figure out [how to install the module with the Python version Thonny is using](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/wiki/InstallingPackages), or change Thonny to also use Python 3.9.

Comment: @Boris Thank you for your help. I think I'll skip the headache of figuring out how to install libraries for different versions of Python on Windows and switch to Wing.

Comment: @Boris You solved my question with comments. If you post your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I recommend using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) (or [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) if you can afford it) for developing in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said

> This issue occurs only in the Thonny IDE, not in the Python shell or IDLE
>
> Thonny uses Python 3.7.9, whereas I use Python 3.9 otherwise

Your issue happens almost certainly because you installed Pillow for Python 3.9 and not for 3.7. Judging from [Thonny's documentation on installing packages](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/wiki/InstallingPackages) you should be able to open a shell and do

```sh
python3.7 -m pip install Pillow
```

and then you'll be able to import Pillow in Thonny as well.

You can confirm which Python version the `pip3` command is using using `pip3 --version`. For example on my Ubuntu system I have the system Python 3.8 and also Python 3.9, so I get this:

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 20.3.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
$ python3.8 -m pip --version
pip 20.3.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```